# Include font icons in Application Bar of Windows Phone 8 Silverlight App

Tags: windows, silverlight, windows-phone-8

Is there any way to include font icons instead of in the Application bar of windows phone 8 silverlight app. This is to reduce the space to store images required for ApplicationBar.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, sorry. You can use icon fonts for the AppBar in WP 8.1 XAML apps, but not 8.x SL apps.

Having said that, images are not going to affect the space all that much, esp if you use the icons from modernuiicons.com.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can't use fonts directly, but Syncfusion have a free tool called [Metro Studio](https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/metrostudio) that will allow you to easily generate AppBar icons from fonts.